# Thomas-Fermi approximation for cold atoms in a 1D harmonic potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bose-einstein-condensate, cold-atoms

The Time-independent Gross-Pitaevskii equation is

$$
\mu{\phi(x)}=\Big(\frac{-\hbar^{2}}{2m}\nabla^{2}+V_{ext}(x)+g|\phi(x)|^{2}\Big)\phi(x)
$$

From Thomas-Fermi approximation,

$$
\phi(x)=\sqrt{\frac{\mu-V_{ext}(x)}{g}} \quad\text{where}\quad \mu>V_{ext}(x)
$$
and $\phi(x)=0$ elsewhere.

The particle density, $n(x)=|\phi(x)|^{2}$ and it is normalized to $\int \mathrm{d}x\;n(x)=\int\mathrm{d}x\;|\phi(x)|^2=N$, where $N$ is the total number of particles.

If the trapping potential is a 1D harmonic potential, $V_{ext}(x)=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}x^{2}$, how do I solve it for this one dimensional case ?

What are the solutions for N and $\mu$ ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$
n(x)=|\phi(x)|^{2}=\frac{\mu-V_{ext}(x)}{g}=\frac{2\mu-m\omega^{2}x^{2}}{2g}
$$
As you can see when $|x|$ goes to $\infty$, $n(x)$ becomes $-ve$, that is unphysical.

We can define the Thomas-Fermi radius, $R_{TF}$ such that $n(x=R_{TF})=0$,
$$
\mu=\frac{m\omega^{2}R_{TF}^{2}}{2}
$$
So the corrected Thomas-Fermi density profile is,
$$
n(x)=\frac{m\omega^{2}\big(R_{TF}^{2}-x^{2}\big)}{2g}\Theta(R_{TF}^{2}-x^{2})
$$
where $\Theta(t)$ is the *Heaviside function*.

**Note**:the density profile $n(x)$ is an inverted parabola with the maximum density at the center.

The number of particles $\mathcal{N}$ within the Thomas-Fermi profile ,

$$
\mathcal{N}=\int_{x}n(x)dx=\int_{-R_{TF}}^{+R_{TF}}\frac{m\omega^{2}(R_{TF}^{2}-x^{2})}{2g}dx=\frac{2m}{3g}R_{TF}^{3}\omega^{2}
$$
Substitute $\mu=\frac{m\omega^{2}R_{TF}^{2}}{2}\rightarrow R=\Big(\frac{2\mu}{m\omega^{2}}\Big)^{1/2}$
$$
N=\frac{2}{3}\frac{(2\mu)^{3/2}}{g\omega\sqrt{m}}
$$

Comment: Is your last line really defining the chemical potential in terms of $N$, $g$, $\omega$, and $m$? Or is it giving the number of particles that are in the ground state/in the condensate?